# How to Save HTML of a div in Database Properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am getting an e**ditable html div** value through `html` function like this.

```
  var progressDesc            =  $jquery("#progressDesc_" +recordId).html();
```

As I want to store, every space and every new line of the editable text (actually the whole format of user input).

And Here is the source of the html input:

```
<div id='progressDesc_"+ data[i].project_progress_id + "' contenteditable='true'>" + data[i].progress_description + " </div>
```

It was working fine but one day I got the error in one html div. The problem is some of the input are save wrong I mean, user save the input with additional div tag which has spoil the html format and wrong data has saved.

I am unable to understand the right way to handle this problem. How do I ensure that html input should be in correct format that it save the proper main div completely.

The Wrong HTML input data sample is given below, as you can see that it has also included my next html button which is not correct. I don't know whats wrong happen with it.

```
<div>
<span style="background-color: transparent;">- QA+Fixing - wip</span>
</div>

<div>- - - - - - - - - - - - -<br></div>

<div>
<span style="background-color: transparent;">-</span>
<span style="background-color: transparent;">&nbsp;</span>
<span style="background-color: transparent;">Excel corrections - done</span>
<span style="background-color: transparent;"><br></span></div>

<div>
<span style="background-color: transparent;">-</span>
<span style="background-color: transparent;">&nbsp;</span>
<span style="background-color: transparent;">Standard OLA - 60%</span>
<br>
</div>

<div>
<span style="background-color: transparent;">-</span>
<span style="background-color: transparent;">&nbsp;</span>SPW from JPG data - 50%<br>
</div>

<div>

<span style="background-color: transparent;">-</span>
<span style="background-color: transparent;">&nbsp;</span>
<span style="background-color: transparent;">Extension floor at start</span>
<span style="background-color: transparent;">&nbsp;</span>
<span style="background-color: transparent;">- 20%</span><br>

</div>

<div>
<div><span style="background-color: transparent;">-</span>
<span style="background-color: transparent;">&nbsp;</span>
Merge Dorfen<span style="background-color: transparent;">&nbsp;</span>
<span style="background-color: transparent;">- 80%</span></div>

<div><span style="background-color: transparent;">-</span>
<span style="background-color: transparent;">&nbsp;</span>
Merge Wasentegern<span style="background-color: transparent;">&nbsp;</span>
<span style="background-color: transparent;">- 50%</span></div>

</div>

<div>
<span style="background-color: transparent;">- QA and fixing planning - done</span>
<br></div><div><span style="background-color: transparent;">- QA</span><span style="background-color: transparent;">&nbsp;</span>
<span style="background-color: transparent;">and fixing</span><span style="background-color: transparent;">&nbsp;</span>
<span style="background-color: transparent;">ex </span>
</div>

<button class="" onclick="ProjectProgressAddNewProje
```

Comment: What is the exact error and how does it come out of the database?

Comment: I have posted the wrong input html sample in the question.

Comment: It is dangerous anyway. Users can mess the html or be malicious with your database. The proper way is to sanitize each entry, store values, and build back the html when needed? It will avoid this kind of issues by the way.
If you really want to do it this way, you can try to json encode the whole, store the json, and decode only on client side, it should work.